# Activate a relay on Schedule

Tags: c

I have a problem to well understand what'is happening here.
I'm tring to activate a relay base on time with the user selected schedule.
The problem is when the stop time is after midnight and the start if before.
My function to check if it is the moment to toggle is:

```
bool lightsOn = false;
void checkOnOff() {
    //Check time for ON/OFF the ligth
  struct tm *curTime = getTime();
  unsigned int now = curTime->tm_hour * 100 + curTime->tm_min;
  unsigned int start = config.ligths_on_time.tm_hour * 100 + config.ligths_on_time.tm_min;
  unsigned int stop = config.ligths_off_time.tm_hour * 100 + config.ligths_off_time.tm_min;

  if ( (now >= start || now < stop) && (now <= stop) ) { //<-- this line is hard to have it in mind
    if(!lightsOn) enableLights();
  } else {
    if(lightsOn) disableLights();
  }
}

void enableLights() { //the same for disableLights() but with false, reverse HIGH/LOW and 0
  lightsOn = true;
  digitalWrite(EXTRA_LED_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ON_OFF_RELAY_PIN, HIGH);
  sendLightsOnOffToServer(1);
  Serial.println(F("Lights enabled."));
}

struct tm *getTime() {
  //if (NTP_TIME_SETTED) {
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    //gmtime_r(&now, &timeinfo); //utc
    return localtime(&now);
  //}
}
```

Is someone can explain to me how to do that ?

Comment: It is not clear what `getTime()` does, does the returned `tm` structure include date information?

Comment: Why are you multiplying hour by 100 not 60?

Comment: getTime() return the current localtime in curTime, setted by NTP.

Comment: @Clifford. 22h10 return 2210, easy to read.

Comment: OK wrong question.  Do the `ligths_on_time` and `ligths_off_time` include date information?

Comment: OK, but in this case you are not reading it - the computer is reading it - the computer does not care, you are performing arithmetic and comparisons on it.

Comment: Doesn't matter about the date information so long as the start and stop are no more than 24 hours separate as your code implies.

Comment: Yes, you have it. And the "x100" is just for Log.

Comment: For clarity you might have either `ON = true` /  `ON = false`, or `ON_OFF = ON` / ON_OFF = OFF`.  `ON_OFF` is not a clearly Boolean name where true or false, have meaning.  When you read `ON_OFF == true` you have to look else where in the code to figure out the non-obvious semantics of that.  ALL-CAPS for variable names is also unconventional, and usually reserved for constants.  I'd suggest `bool lightOn = false;` then you have simpler tests such as `if( lightOn )` / `if( !lightOn)`, then it reads in natural language just like the semantics of the code _"if light on"_,  _"if not light on"_.

Comment: Yes you are right! I'll correct this for sure to avoid future confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Adjust the `stop` time by 24 hours if it is smaller than `start`
- Adjust the `now` time by 24 hours if the stop time is tomorrow, and the ON_OFF state is ON, and now < start.
- Re-order your logic to use the ON_OFF state to determine whether to check for start or stop

```
#define HOUR 100
#define DAY (HOUR * 24)
#define ON   true
#define OFF  false

unsigned int now = curTime->tm_hour * HOUR + 
                   curTime->tm_min ;

unsigned int start = config.ligths_on_time.tm_hour * HOUR + 
                     config.ligths_on_time.tm_min;

unsigned int stop = config.ligths_off_time.tm_hour * HOUR  + 
                    config.ligths_off_time.tm_min;

// Fix-up stop and now time to account for stop in next day
if( stop < start) 
{
    stop += DAY ;
    if( ON_OFF == ON && now < start )
    {
        now += DAY ;
    }
}

// If OFF, check for start condition
if( ON_OFF == OFF && now >= start )
{
    enableLight() ;
}
// ... otherwise if ON, check for stop condition
else if( ON_OFF == ON && now >= stop )
{
    disableLight() ;
}
```

Comment: Looking at this, seems to be the correct answer. I'll check later, I'm not working on it at the moment. Thanks for your time @Clifford

Comment: @Cliiford Just try. Sorry but that isn't doing the job. When it just passed OFF, ON_OFF is OFF and now is greter than start so it is going ON again, then OFF, then...

Comment: So, finally, adding " && now < stop " here: if( ON_OFF == OFF && now >= start && now < stop ) do the job.

Comment: @JB_DELR ok, I was thinking that the ON_OFF == OFF and now < stop were mutually exclusive when now >= start.  I'd have to think about that, but you got there in any case.